# What are the requirements to use __float128?

Tags: c, floating-point

I'm not really sure how I can find out of a system does or doesn't support the `__float128` type. What system requirements have to be met for this to be available, and is there a way to check if those requirements are met in C code? (For reference, my system supports `__int128` but not `__float128`.)

Comment: Anything beginning with an underscore will be very compiler-specific and non-portable. It's more of a compiler than system issue (or perhaps a mix of both).

Comment: Ah, okay. My question about detecting this still stands, though.

Comment: When you say you want to "detect" it, can you please elaborate? Detect it in a configuration script or similar? Through the use of preprocessor macros? Some other way? To "detect" something like this depends more on your environment and how you're configuring and building your project.

Comment: Preprocessor macros.

Comment: As mentioned in [the answer by Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66049659/440558) it might not be possible by using preprocessor macros alone. If you have some kind of configuration script or project generator (say GNU Autotools or CMake or similar) then you could ask the script to check for the type. Otherwise there's probably no way to reliably detect its availability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you are asking about GCC, [clause 6.12 of the documentation for GCC 10.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/Floating-Types.html#Floating-Types) says:

> … `__float128` is available on i386, x86_64, IA-64, and hppa HP-UX, as well as on PowerPC GNU/Linux targets that enable the vector scalar (VSX) instruction set. `__float128` supports the 128-bit floating type. On i386, x86_64, PowerPC, and IA-64 other than HP-UX, `__float128` is an alias for `_Float128`. On hppa and IA-64 HP-UX, `__float128` is an alias for `long double`…

and:

> … In order to use `_Float128`, `__float128`, and `__ibm128` on PowerPC Linux systems, you must use the `-mfloat128` option. It is expected in future versions of GCC that `_Float128` and `__float128` will be enabled automatically…

I do not see an in-source test for the type, such as a preprocessor macro that would indicate it.

Comment: Hm, running `uname -m` gives me `x86_64`, so theoretically my system should support it?

Comment: Unless I'm not understanding something (which is probably true), my system should be compatible, even though it isn't.

Comment: @fluffyyboii: What's your compiler version?

Comment: ```Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: @fluffyyboii: I do not see mention of `__float128` in [the Clang documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html).

Comment: `__int128` isn't in there either but that's supported. (I'm using `gcc` but idk if that's different or not)

Comment: At least for C++ gcc has a macro _GLIBCXX_USE_FLOAT128

Comment: [An answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69742223/675721) says that Apple Clang doesn't support __float128