# Why is __float128 not supported?

Tags: c, gcc

So I tried to do very precise math in C using a `__float128`-type.

My code looks something like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    __float128 num;
}
```

I tried compiling it without any options like this:

```c
gcc -o test test.c
```

The error I get is:

```
test.c:4:5: error: __float128 is not supported on this target
```

My gcc was installed using Homebrew on an x86 Macbook.

Comment: Libraries are more than just headers. A header is just a list of stuff that's in the library. It's not the actual library.

Comment: Are you on an Intel (x86) Mac or an Apple Silicon (ARM) Mac?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I use a x86 MacBook Air from 2019.

Comment: Wait a minute. Libquadmath doesn't provide __float128; it depends on it already being available. Is there anything you're actually using from libquadmath? What happens if you just remove `#include <quadmath.h>`?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica `test.c:4:5: error: __float128 is not supported on this target`

Comment: Okay, that's your actual problem and it has nothing to do with libquadmath. You should edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Am I describing my problem in the right way?

Comment: What is the output of `gcc --version`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My gcc was installed using Homebrew on an x86 Macbook.

You may have done that, but the `gcc` that you ran to compile your test program is actually Apple clang disguised as GCC, as you'll see if you do `gcc -v`. Apple clang doesn't support __float128, but the real GCC does. Do `/usr/local/bin/gcc-11 -o test test.c` to use the real GCC that you installed, and then it should compile successfully.

Comment: Now it tells me that `In file included from test.c:1:
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0/lib/gcc/11/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin21/11.2.0/include-fixed/stdio.h:78:10: fatal error: _stdio.h: No such file or directory`.

Comment: @gurkensaas Try redoing `xcode-select --install`.

Comment: I will have to come back to you later, there was just another Software Update including some changes to the command line tools. Lets see if that changes anything.

Comment: On my Linux systems, clang does support `__float128`. How come Apple version of it doesn't?

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly for me. What identifier does `__float128` use when printing it?

Comment: @gurkensaas You mean what format specifier? That would be `%Qg`, but take note that you'll probably have to use [`quadmath_snprintf`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libquadmath/quadmath_005fsnprintf.html) since you're not using glibc (which is basically what it means by "some targets").

Comment: I tried that, but it gives me the error `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_quadmath_snprintf", referenced from:
      _main in cciJWyME.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: @gurkensaas To use libquadmath, just including the header isn't enough. You also need to add `-lquadmath` to the end of the GCC command line.

Comment: Is this the right syntax: `quadmath_snprintf("hello world", 11, "%Qg", num);`?

Comment: @gurkensaas You can't overwrite a string literal. You'd want to do `char str[11]; quadmath_snprintf(str, 11, "%Qg", num);` instead.

Comment: @gurkensaas but please don't specify the `11` literally in the arguments, use `sizeof str`. Otherwise a change of size of `str` will require you to edit the value at least in two places, some of which you might forget to update. See also [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY_principle).